# Is it possible to add HTML in a CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I know you can add CSS in an HTML code, but what I want to know is that is it possible to do the opposite? Because there's something I want to add a class to, but it only has a custom CSS box.

EDIT:

```
<div class="thing2"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t7vzjbr) - What I wanna try to do here is to make the ".thing2" appear by only putting codes on the css box and not adding the code above in the html box. Just wanted to see if it's even possible.

Comment: There's the css property `content`, and the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors, but none of them add additional HTML to the document.

Comment: Do you know JavaScript ? Can you use it ?  with CSS won't be possible to manipulate your DOM..

Comment: No its not possible right now may be in future :)

Comment: No, but there are ways to add CSS with JavaScript... I guess it just depends on what you're trying to do and why. Code examples are always good to have.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do it using JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementId");
element.className = element.className + " newclass";
```

Hope this helps spark some ideas!

Comment: Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/8t7vzjbr - I'm trying to make ".thing2" appear. Would it be possible to only put that code in the css box and not in the js box? I'm still new to js, so yep. In the thing I'm customizing, they only have a custom css box, so I'm really not sure how to add that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function (javascript) like

```
function myfunc()
{
    var something = document.getElementById("ElementID");
    something.className = something.className + " newclass";
}
```

then just call it

Comment: Can you try the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/8t7vzjbr/ ? I'm trying to make ".thing2" appear with no html codes